# aws s3 ls The read operation timed out

Tags: amazon-s3

I try to get a huge list of files from AWS S3 bucket with this command:

```
aws s3 ls --human-readable --recursive my-directory
```

This directory contains tens of thousands of files, so *sometimes*, after long pause, I get this error:

```
('The read operation timed out',)
```

I've tried parameter `--page-size` with different values, but it didn't help. How can I fix this error?

Comment: I see two potential reason = 1) https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=161807 - comes from system level issue(linux kernel) and 2) not fresh version cli tool.

Comment: Thanks, Rinat. My version is `aws-cli/1.10.41 Python/2.7.11+ Linux/4.4.0-28-generic botocore/1.4.31`, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me (that's why I'm here). I just had to run it again a couple more times and it worked. I'm not saying that's the solution, but maybe it's only a temporary malfunction.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can anyone respond that how did you manage to display huge list of objects?

Comment: A couple of ideas to try out, if you haven't already:
1) I don't want to be repetitive, but this question is old and there have been several CLI releases since then. Try updating it;
2) You can experiment with the cli timeouts, like `--cli-connect-timeout`, `--no-cli-read-timeout`, and `--no-cli-connect-timeout` and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to loop the sync of S3 bucket till transfer is done. The script would look like:

```
while:
do
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/path-to-files
done
```

This would retry if file transfer fails and basically resume downloading again and again till the transfer is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there're a lot of improvements for aws cli. Now when I run the cmd with 17000+ plus files in s3, it only took less than 30 seconds, as shown below:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1372  100  1318  100    54   2404     98 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2409
   17579
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not wise to read huge data in a distributed system. It is a block on the server and as well as to the client.

If you have a pattern of how the data is stored, try to run them in parallel and later append to a single file.

E.g.,

aws s3 ls s3://bucket/year/month  --recursive

Hope it helps.